# Faster Method Of Calculating Portfolio Volatility

Tags: python, numpy, numba, volatility

I am writing a numba function to calculate a portfolio's volatility:

[image]

Some functions that I am using to do this are here:

```
import numba as nb
import numpy as np

def portfolio_s2( cv, weights ):
    """ Calculate the variance of a portfolio """
    return weights.dot( cv ).dot( weights )

@nb.jit( nopython=True )
def portfolio_s2c( cv, weights ):

    s0 = 0.0
    for i in range( weights.shape[0]-1 ):
        wi = weights[i]
        s0 += cv[i,i]*wi*wi
        s1 = 0.0
        for j in range( i+1, weights.shape[0] ):
            s1 += wi*weights[j]*cv[i,j]
        s0 += 2.0*s1

    i = weights.shape[0]-1 
    wi = weights[ i ]
    s0 += cv[i,i]*wi**2
    return s0

@nb.jit( nopython=True )
def portfolio_s2b( cv, weights ):

    s0 = 0.0
    for i in range( weights.shape[0] ):
        s0 += weights[i]*weights[i]*cv[i,i]

    s1 = 0.0
    for i in range( weights.shape[0]-1 ):
        s2 = 0.0
        for j in range( i+1, weights.shape[0] ):
            s2 += weights[j]*cv[i,j]
        s1+= weights[i]*s2
    return s0+2.0*s1
```

I am testing the performance of the functions using this code:

```
    N = 1000
    num_tests = 10000

    times_2b = []
    times_2c = []
    times_np = []

    matrix_sizes = [ 2,4,8, 10, 20, 40, 80, 160 ]#, 320, 640, 1280, 2560 ]

    for m in matrix_sizes:
        X = np.random.randn( N, m )
        cv = np.cov( X, rowvar=0 )

        w = np.ones( cv.shape[0] ) / cv.shape[0]

        s2 = helpers.portfolio_s2( cv, w )
        s2b = helpers.portfolio_s2b( cv, w )
        s2c = helpers.portfolio_s2c( cv, w )

        np.testing.assert_almost_equal( s2, s2b ) 
        np.testing.assert_almost_equal( s2, s2c )               

        with Timer( 'nb2b' ) as t2b:
            for _ in range(num_tests):
                helpers.portfolio_s2b( cv, w )

        with Timer( 'nb2c' ) as t2c:
            for _ in range(num_tests):
                helpers.portfolio_s2c( cv, w )                

        with Timer( 'np' ) as tnp:
            for _ in range(num_tests):
                helpers.portfolio_s2( cv, w )

        times_2b.append( t2b.timetaken )
        times_2c.append( t2c.timetaken )
        times_np.append( tnp.timetaken )

    plt.figure()
    plt.plot( matrix_sizes, times_2b, label='2b' )
    plt.plot( matrix_sizes, times_2c, label='2c' )
    plt.plot( matrix_sizes, times_np, label='np' )
    plt.legend(loc='center left', bbox_to_anchor=(1, 0.5))
    plt.show()
```

This is the Timer class:

```
import time
class Timer( object ):

    def __init__(self, name=''):
        self._name = name

    def __enter__(self):
        self.start = time.time()
        return self        

    def __exit__(self,a,b,c):
        self.end = time.time()
        self.timetaken = self.end-self.start
        print( '{0} Took {1} seconds'.format( self._name, self.timetaken ))
```

The results are plotted here:

[image]

The results show that:

- The numba versions of the function outperform the numpy version for matrix sizes under 80
- The numba versions seem to scale worse than the numpy function

Why is this? Is there some sort of overhead associated with calling numpy, as opposed to calling numba?

Why does the numpy function scale better? Is it doing something fancy with BLAS in the background, or is it using a superior algorithm for the calculation?

Can I make the numba function scale as well as the numpy function?

Comment: *"Is it doing something fancy with BLAS in the background?"* - in a nutshell, yes. `np.dot` calls a BLAS `*gemm` function. Its performance will vary depending on the exact BLAS library your version of numpy is linked against (MKL and OpenBLAS are typically the fastest), but you can expect it to be multithreaded and probably *very* hard to beat with a JIT compiler for reasonably large matrices.

Comment: The upcoming release of numpy (http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/release.html - although the link will age very quickly) has a function `multi_dot` that chains together multiple dot products, and will presumably speed up numpy further.

Comment: The `mullti_dot` just desides whether it is faster to do `(AB)C` or `A(BC)`.

Comment: @DavidW `multi_dot` would probably be slower, since there will be additional overhead involved in working out the optimal evaluation order, which is already identical to the current order `w.dot(cv).dot(w)`

Comment: Fair point - I assumed it might do something cleverer (which I guess it might in principle in future, but certainly not right now)